Power call option pricing problem
Q: The payoff of a European ’power call’ is given by $max(S^\alpha - K,0)$. Derive the price of a European power call option.

I've keep arriving at a different solution compared to standard references. Specifically, my confusion lies in (II) of the expectation calculation. Here’s the setup and where my derivation diverges: Under $Q$, the Black-Scholes framework, the dynamics of $S_t$ follow a Geometric Brownian Motion (GBM):
$$
dS_t = r S_t \, dt + \sigma S_t \, dW_t
$$
$$
d(\ln S_t^\alpha) = \alpha \left( r - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \right) dt + \alpha \sigma dW^Q_t
$$
$$
S_t^\alpha = S_0^\alpha \exp \left( \alpha \left( r - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \right) T + \alpha \sigma W_T^Q \right)
$$

The power call option price is:
$$
C_0 = \underbrace{e^{-rT} \mathbb{E}^Q[S_T^\alpha \mathbf{1}_{S_T^\alpha > K}]}_{(II)} - \underbrace{e^{-rT} K \mathbb{E}^Q[\mathbf{1}_{S_T^\alpha > K}]}_{(I)}
$$

I:
$$
e^{-rT} K \mathbb{E}^Q[\mathbf{1}_{S_T^\alpha > K}] = e^{-rT} K Q(S_T^\alpha > K)
$$
$$
= e^{-rT} K Q \left( S_0^\alpha \exp \left( \alpha \left( r - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \right) T + \alpha \sigma W_T^Q \right) > K \right)
$$
$$
= e^{-rT} K \Phi \left( \frac{-\ln K + \ln S_0^\alpha + \alpha (r - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2) T}{\alpha \sigma \sqrt{T}} \right)
$$
$$
= e^{-rT} K \Phi \left( \frac{-\ln X + \ln S_0 + (r - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2) T}{\sigma \sqrt{T}} \right): X = K^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}
$$

II:
$$
e^{-rT} \mathbb{E}^Q[S_T^\alpha \mathbf{1}_{S_T^\alpha > K}] = e^{-rT} \mathbb{E}^Q \left[ S_0^\alpha \exp \left( \alpha \left( r - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \right) T + \alpha \sigma W_T^Q \right) \mathbf{1}_{S_T^\alpha > K} \right]
$$
After simplifying, I arrive at:
$$
S_0^\alpha \exp \left( (\alpha - 1) \left( r + \frac{\alpha \sigma^2}{2} \right) T \right) Q(S_T^\alpha > K)
$$

Issue: The $N(d_1)$ in Part II doesn't match the typical solutions I find online. Can someone point out where my derivation might be going wrong?

The specific Black-Scholes solution I'm referencing is detailed here: https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PricingPowerOptionsInTheBlackScholesModel/ - where part II. looks like the following:
$$
S_0^\alpha \exp \left( (\alpha - 1) \left( r + \frac{\alpha \sigma^2}{2} \right) T \right) \Phi \left( \frac{-\ln K + \ln S^\alpha_0 + \alpha(r + (\alpha - \frac{1}{2}) \sigma^2) T}{\sigma \alpha \sqrt{T}} \right)
$$

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

From Mark Joshi, The Use of Power Numeraires in Option Pricing, 2003: Powers of the stock price, $S^\alpha_T$, are also not representable as self-financing contracts for $\alpha \ne 0, 1$, since their discounted value is not a martingale in the risk-neutral measure. We therefore adopt the solution of taking a contract that pays a given power of the stock price at a fixed time $T$. Its price process is then trivially valid as a numeraire whilst having similar but not identical properties to $S^\alpha_T$. We can let $N^{\alpha}_{t,T}$ be the value at time $t$ of a derivative that pays $S^{\alpha}_T$ at time $T$. It follows by risk-neutral valuation that:
$$
N^{\alpha}_{t,T} = e^{-r(T-t)} \mathbb{E} \left[ S^{\alpha}_T \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] = S^{\alpha}_t exp \left( (T-t)(r(\alpha-1) + 0.5\sigma^2 (\alpha^2 - \alpha)) \right).
$$
$$
dN^{\alpha}_{t,T} = d \left( S^{\alpha}_t exp \left( (T-t)(r(\alpha-1) + 0.5\sigma^2 (\alpha^2 - \alpha)) \right) \right) =  r N^{\alpha}_{t,T} dt + \sigma N^{\alpha}_{t,T} \alpha dW_t.
$$
The process for $N^{\alpha}_{t,T}$ - using itô's lemma - is thus log-normal with drift $r$ and volatility $\sigma\alpha$ in the risk-neutral measure. The discounted value of $N^{\alpha}_{t,T}$ is a martingale in the risk-neutral measure - and used as numeraire. The Radon–Nikodym derivative of the $\alpha$-measure change - and the $S^\alpha_t$ dynamics in $Q_\alpha$
$$
\frac{dQ_\alpha}{dQ} \big|_{\mathcal{F}_T} = exp \left( -\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2 \sigma^2T + \alpha \sigma W^Q_T  \right)
$$
$$
S_T^\alpha =  S_0^\alpha \exp \left( \alpha \left( r - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \right) T + \alpha \sigma (W^{Q_\alpha}_T + \sigma \alpha T ) \right)
$$
Going back to the (in)famous last step
$$
S_0^\alpha \exp \left( (\alpha - 1) \left( r + \frac{\alpha \sigma^2}{2} \right) T \right) \mathbb{E}^Q \left[\mathbf{1}_{S_T^\alpha > K} \right] 
$$
$$
= N^{\alpha}_{0,T} \mathbb{E}^Q \left[ \color{red}{\frac{dQ_\alpha}{dQ}} \mathbf{1}_{S_T^\alpha > K} \right] = N^{\alpha}_{0,T} \mathbb{E}^{Q_\alpha} \left[\mathbf{1}_{S_T^\alpha > K} \right] = N^{\alpha}_{0,T} Q_\alpha(S_T^\alpha > K) 
$$
$$
= N^{\alpha}_{0,T} Q_\alpha( S_0^\alpha \exp \left( \alpha \left( r - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \right) T + \alpha \sigma (W^{Q_\alpha}_T + \sigma \alpha T ) \right) > K) 
$$
$$
= N^{\alpha}_{0,T} Q_\alpha \left( \frac{W^{Q_\alpha}_T}{\sqrt{T}} > \frac{lnK - lnS_0^\alpha - \alpha (r - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)T - \alpha^2 \sigma^2 T}{\alpha \sigma\sqrt{T}} \right) 
$$
Q.1: In the above derivation, where does $\frac{dQ^{\alpha}}{dQ}$ come from? It seems intuitive and perhaps trivial, but I’m struggling to grasp it at the moment. For a vanilla payoff $(S_T - K)^+$, we typically introduce the Radon-Nikodym derivative by substituting $ S_T$ inside the expectation to switch to the stock measure. However, in this case, it appears to emerge unexpectedly. What am I missing?

I am confused about your exact claim. In the link to wolfram, there is exactly the same d1 as my derivation. While the formula you copied afterwards is clearly wrong as it misses an alpha in front of ln(s). If you could just write the 2 expressions of d1 you are confused about, then it will be easier to answer.

Apologies if my question is not intuitive - I made an edit for clarity.

A.1:
$$
S_0^\alpha \exp \left( (\alpha - 1) \left( r + \frac{\alpha \sigma^2}{2} \right) T \right) \mathbb{E}^Q \left[\mathbf{1}_{S_T^\alpha > K} \right] 
$$
$$
= N^{\alpha}_{0,T} \mathbb{E}^{Q_\alpha} \left[\frac{dQ}{dQ_\alpha} \mathbf{1}_{S_T^\alpha > K} \right] = N^{\alpha}_{0,T} \mathbb{E}^{Q_\alpha} \left[\frac{N^{\alpha}_{0,T}B_T}{N^{\alpha}_{T,T}} \mathbf{1}_{S_T^\alpha > K} \right] 
$$
$$
= N^{\alpha}_{0,T} \mathbb{E}^{Q_\alpha} \left[\frac{N^{\alpha}_{0,T}B_T}{S^{\alpha}_T } \mathbf{1}_{S_T^\alpha > K} \right] = N^{\alpha}_{0,T} Q_\alpha(S_T^\alpha > K)
$$
A.2:
$$
e^{-rT} \mathbb{E}^Q[S_T^\alpha \mathbf{1}_{S_T^\alpha > K}] = e^{-rT} \mathbb{E}^{Q_\alpha} \left[\frac{dQ}{dQ_\alpha} S_T^\alpha \mathbf{1}_{S_T^\alpha > K} \right] 
$$
$$
= e^{-rT} \mathbb{E}^{Q_\alpha} \left[ \frac{N^{\alpha}_{0,T}B_T}{S^{\alpha}_T} S_T^\alpha \mathbf{1}_{S_T^\alpha > K} \right] = N^{\alpha}_{0,T} Q_\alpha(S_T^\alpha > K)
$$

I think there is a simpler approach.
$Y_t = S_t^{\alpha}$
$dY_t = \alpha S_t^{\alpha-1} dS_t + \frac{1}{2} \alpha (\alpha - 1) S_t^{\alpha -2} <dS_t, dS_t>$
which simplifies as
$dY_t = \alpha S_t^{\alpha} r dt + \alpha S_t^{\alpha} \sigma dW_t + \frac{1}{2} \alpha (\alpha - 1) S_t^{\alpha} \sigma^2 dt$
$dY_t = \alpha Y_t r dt + \alpha Y_t \sigma dW_t + \frac{1}{2} \alpha (\alpha - 1) Y_t \sigma^2 dt = \alpha (r + \frac{1}{2} (\alpha - 1) \sigma^2 ) Y_t dt + \alpha \sigma Y_t dW_t$
Which means you can use the standard BS formula with a different forward and volatility, but the same discount factor.
The forward is $S_0^{\alpha} e^{\alpha (r + \frac{1}{2} (\alpha - 1) \sigma^2) T}$, while the volatility is $\alpha \sigma$.
EDIT: after reading your comment.
$d_2$ is correct, you can just use the normal one with $K^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}$. This is under the bank account measure which has not changed.
$d_1 = \frac{\log F - \log K + \frac{1}{2} \text{vol}^2 T}{\text{vol} \sqrt{T}}$ or, with our values
$d_1 = \frac{\alpha ( \log S + (r + \frac{1}{2} (\alpha-1) \sigma^2 ) T) - \log K + \frac{1}{2} \alpha^2 \sigma^2 T}{\alpha \sigma \sqrt{T}}$
which becomes
$d_1 = \frac{\log S -\log X + (r + \frac{1}{2} (\alpha-1) \sigma^2 + \frac{1}{2} \alpha \sigma^2) T}{\sigma \sqrt{T}}$
$d_1 = \frac{\log S - \log X + (r + (\alpha - \frac{1}{2}) \sigma^2 ) T}{\sigma \sqrt{T}}$
I see you added the link, where $d_1$ looks like mine. I am a bit lost in what your 2 alternative expressions are. You should probably write them next to each other to avoid confusion.

Ciao Andrea! Thanks for your response. My question was more about understanding where I might be going wrong in my derivation process, rather than just finding a solution to the exercise. I’m trying to pinpoint what’s keeping me stuck so I can gain a deeper understanding. Thanks again for your help!

Thanks again for the update! I apologize if my question was unclear. To clarify: Part (I) corresponds to the right side of the Black-Scholes formula, $e^{-rT} K N(d_2)$, while Part (II) aligns with the left side. In my formulation of the power call option price, I’ve used underbraces to label these parts for reference.
